# WebAPI method with file and body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a WebAPI method as shown below. Uploading a file works just fine with that, but I also need an additional object with information on how to handle the file. What I have tried so far:

```
//Works fine but no body defined
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(string id, IFormFile file)
{
    //Do stuff
    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

and

```
public class UploadFile
{
    //As simple example
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Keys { get; set; }
}

//What I would like to have, but doesn't work
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult PutTest(string id, IFormFile file, [FromBody] UploadFile info)
{
    //Do stuff
    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

using SwaggerUI with the following input:

[image]

I get a 400 Bad Request back with the message `"The input was not valid."`. SwaggerUI shows the following cURL for the request (which does not seem to contain any info on the body):

```
curl -X PUT "https://localhost:5001/api/Document/test/test.txt" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -d {"file":{}}
```

How can I best approach this to get the result I would like?

Comment: What is the result you like? Where are you stuck. Do you need help on how to call the endpoint or is something in the api itself not working?

Comment: @Marco I've used SwaggerUI to call the method. With the solution I described in the second code block it gives me a 400 back with `"The input was not valid."`, even though the fields in SwaggerUI show the format as I would expect.

Comment: We really can't help you, until you've described what your input parameters were, so we can actually reproduce this behaviour. So please use postman to test and then provide us with the request details and the exact error message.

Comment: @Marco I think the problem is that I can't have an IformFile and FromBody in a single request even though the project allows it at compilation, although it could also be that my request is bad. I'm just kinda stuck with not knowing the exact issue to find a proper solution myself. Added more info to the question.

Comment: You could not combine `form-data` and `application/json` in the same request. Try to change `FromBody` to `FromForm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to wrap IFormFile and your UploadFile into single view model:

```
public class FileViewModel{ 
    public UploadFile UploadFile{get;set;} 
    public IFormFile File {get; set;}
}
```

then

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult PutTest(string id, FileViewModel vm)
{
//Do stuff
return StatusCode(200);
}
```

Comment: Tried it and it might work, but I'm not sure how to build up the request in e.g. Postman for it. Whatever I try I get a 400 back with `"file": [
    "Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'file', line 2, position 12."`